# Does this problem have an “exact” solution?

Tags: r, optimization, algorithms

I am working with R.

Suppose you have the following data:

```r
    #generate data
    set.seed(123)
    a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
    b1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
    c1 = rnorm(1000,5,1)
    train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
    
    #view data
             a1        b1       c1
    1  94.39524  90.04201 4.488396
    2  97.69823  89.60045 5.236938
    3 115.58708  99.82020 4.458411
    4 100.70508  98.67825 6.219228
    5 101.29288  74.50657 5.174136
    6 117.15065 110.40573 4.384732
```

We can visualize the data as follows:

```r
    #visualize data
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    
    plot(train_data$a1, train_data$b1, col = train_data$c1, 
       main = "plot of a1 vs b1, points colored by c1")
hist(train_data$a1)
    hist(train_data$b1)
hist(train_data$c1)
```

[image]

Here is the **Problem** :

- From the data, only take variables "a1" and "b1" : using o**nly 2
  "logical conditions"**, split this data into **3 regions** (e.g. Region 1
  WHERE 20 > a1 >0 AND 0< b1 < 25)
- In each region, you want the "average value of c1" within that region
  to be as small as possible - but each region must have at least some
  minimum number of data points, e.g. 100 data points (to prevent
  trivial solutions)

**Goal :** Is it possible to determine the "boundaries" of these 3 regions that **minimizes** :

- the mean value of "c1" for region 1
- the mean value of "c1" for region 2
- the mean value of "c1" for region 3
- the average "mean value of c1 for all 3 regions" (i.e. c_avg =
  (`region1_c1_avg + region2_c1_avg + region3_c1_avg) / 3`)

In the end, for a given combination, you would find the following, e.g. (made up numbers):

- Region 1 : WHERE 20> a1 >0 AND 0 < b1 < 25 ; region1_c1_avg = 4
- Region 2 : WHERE 50> a1 >20 AND 25 < b1 < 60 ; region2_c1_avg = 2.9
- Region 3 : WHERE a1>50 AND b1 > 60 ; region3_c1_avg = 1.9
- c_avg = (4 + 2.9 + 1.9) / 3 = 2.93

And hope that (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`) are minimized

**My Question:**

**Does this kind of problem have an "exact solution"?** The only thing I can think of is performing a "random search" that considers many different definitions of (Region 1, Region 2 and Region 3) and compares the corresponding values of (region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg), until a minimum value is found. Is this an application of linear programming or multi-objective optimization (e.g. genetic algorithm)? Has anyone worked on something like this before?

I have done a lot of research and haven't found a similar problem like this. I decided to formulate this problem as a "multi-objective constrained optimization problem", and figured out how to implement algorithms like "random search" and "genetic algorithm". **Can someone please confirm if my general approach to this problem makes sense?**

**Note 1:** In the context of multi-objective optimization, for a given set of definitions of (`Region1, Region2 and Region3`): to collectively compare whether a set of values for (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`) are satisfactory, the concept of "Pareto Optimality" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Visualization_of_the_Pareto_front) is often used to make comparisons between different sets of {(`Region1, Region2 and Region3`) and (`region1_c1_avg, region2_c1_avg, region3_c1_avg and c_avg`)}

**Note 2 :** Ultimately, these 3 Regions can defined by any set of 4 numbers. If each of these 4 numbers can be between "0 and 100", and through 0.1 increments (e.g. 12, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, etc) : this means that there exists 1000 ^ 4 = 1 e^12 possible solutions (roughly 1 trillion) to compare. There are simply far too many solutions to individually verify and compare. I am thinking that a mathematical based search/optimization problem can be used to strategically search for an optimal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just optimization (minimization) where your objective function is the sum of the c_avg values in the regions of interest. Standard optimization libraries can take care of this for you. They can take advantage of computing derivatives of the objective to make it faster than a simple grid search (as you suggest) or completely random search.

Here is a simple example using R's `optim`

```
#generate data
set.seed(123)
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
c1 = rnorm(1000,5,1)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)

obj_fxn <- function(x, min_pts=100, penalty=5){
  idx1 <- which(a1 < x[1] & b1 < x[3])
  idx2 <- which((a1 > x[1]) & (a1 < x[2]) & (b1 > x[3]) & (b1 < x[4]))
  idx3 <- which((a1 > x[2]) & (b1 > x[4]))
  
  lens <- c(length(idx1), length(idx2), length(idx3))
  result <- mean(c1[idx1]) + mean(c1[idx2]) + mean(c1[idx3]) - penalty * min(0, min(lens) - min_pts)
  
  return(result)
}

r <- optim(c(90,110,90,110),obj_fxn, min_pts=100, penalty=1)

plot(train_data$a1, train_data$b1, col = train_data$c1, 
     main = "plot of a1 vs b1, points colored by c1")
abline(v=r$par[1])
abline(v=r$par[2])
abline(h=r$par[3])
abline(h=r$par[4])

x <- r$par
idx1 <- which(a1 < x[1] & b1 < x[3])
idx2 <- which((a1 > x[1]) & (a1 < x[2]) & (b1 > x[3]) & (b1 < x[4]))
idx3 <- which((a1 > x[2]) & (b1 > x[4]))
lens <- c(length(idx1), length(idx2), length(idx3))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify that because this is a *multi-objective* optimization task, there is no single best answer -- instead, one must define a Pareto frontier, as you have done.

Comment: I used a single-objective optimization since it was easy to implement (essentialy this is [linear scalarizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Scalarizing) of a multi-objective optimization with equal weights. If you have some reason to favor one region of the others you can weight them different in the objective function.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean my comment to suggest that you did anything wrong (I meant to +1 earlier), or even should attempt to solve it differently, I just meant to be explicit about the role of `penalty`.

Comment: Oh, I initially added `Inf` to the objective if the minimum number of points was not in each region but `optim` requires the initial parameters to have finite objective so `penalty` was just a more tapered approached to getting minimum number of points in each region

Comment: @bdeonovic: thank you so much for your answer! I have attempted to solve this question using several different optimization algorithm - tomorrow I will post the code for all of these! thanks so much!

Comment: btw: why did you include a penalty term?

Comment: can you please take a look at this question later if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386199/r-error-evaluation-of-vectorized-objective-function-returned-a-malformed-matr thank you